# Dynamic class names in Javascript - with jsfiddle

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get 2 successive items (pie charts) in a row to rotate to different angles, using a local variable in a script, using the JQuery CSS method. The names "a2" and "a3", below, have to be generated dynamically, in a loop. (JST EJS) This is the Javascript:

```
var selector1 = ".thermometer .pieSlice1.hold .pie" + " .a2";
var s1 = 'rotate(130deg)';
$(selector1).css({'background-color': 'cyan'});
$(selector1).css({'-webkit-transform': s1});
$(selector1).css({'-moz-transform': s1});
$(selector1).css({'-o-transform': s1});
$(selector1).css({'transform': s1});
var selector2 = ".thermometer .pieSlice1.hold .pie" + " .a3";
var s2 = 'rotate(65deg)';
$(selector2).css({'background-color': 'cyan'});
$(selector2).css({'-webkit-transform': s1});
$(selector2).css({'-moz-transform': s1});
$(selector2).css({'-o-transform': s1});
$(selector2).css({'transform': s1});
```

In the HTML, I have this:

```
<div class="thermometer">
  <div class="circle green">
    <div class="pieSlice1 hold">
      <div class="pie">
        <div class="a2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="thermometer">
  <div class="circle blue">
    <div class="pieSlice1 hold">
      <div class="pie">
        <div class="a3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why does the matching fail? I find that the Javascript selectors do not match EITHER HTML entity. Why not? The Jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/sploiber/VJHcH/53/

EDIT - just to add a little information. If I remove the "a2" and "a3", the rotation CSS elements work fine. I'm open to better ways to mark the differences between the 2 pies.

Comment: Add some text inside the `<div class="a3">` and call `alert($(selector2).text());` at the bottom of your script and you will see that the selectors are working.  I would look at your `css()` calls

Comment: @JasonSperske, thanks much. The CSS calls work, if I don't have the a2 and a3 (if I am just using "pie"). Somehow, the a2 and a3 aren't the best ways to do it. I'm totally open to suggestions on how to do it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some code that might do what you are looking for ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FSkmr/4/)):

```
function rotate(slice, degree) {
  slice.css({
   '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
   '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
   '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
   '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)',
   'transform': 'rotate(' + degree + 'deg)'
  });
}

var selector1 = ".thermometer .pieSlice1.hold .pie" + " .a2";
rotate($(selector1).parent(), 130);

var selector2 = ".thermometer .pieSlice1.hold .pie" + " .a3";
rotate($(selector2).parent(), 65);
```

So for some explanation for what is going on here.  First the select was working but the element you wanted to actually rotate was the `.parent()` of the `<div class="a2">` and `<div class="a3">`'.  An alternative could also be to use the color of the chart to select this slice.  Also I combined the calls to `.css()` and generalized it to a cleaner function.  In terms of what was wrong, it really all came down to rotating the wrong element.

Comment: thanks so much! Wow!! I am now really curious why my other way didn't work, and yours does. I think I don't understand the function fully.

Comment: Have a look that the other answers for information about fixing your script/css. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors are working fine it seems.

You don't see the .a3 divs because some of the parent divs have a '`clip`' or '`overflow: hidden`' style.

Answer (score 0):

The matching succeeds just fine, but you're matching on the a2 and a3 div which has no content, and hence it makes no difference to CSS transform it. Try to use `parent()` instead:

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/VJHcH/64/)

I've also updated your javascript to work with loops:

```
var selectors = {
    a2: {
        backgroundColor: 'cyan',
        rotation: 130
    },
    a3: {
        backgroundColor: 'cyan',
        rotation: 65
    }
}

var transformCSS;
for (var elementKey in selectors) {
    transformCSS = 'rotate(' + selectors[elementKey].rotation + 'deg)';
    $(".thermometer .pieSlice1.hold .pie ." + elementKey).parent().css({
        'background-color': selectors[elementKey].backgroundColor,
        '-webkit-transform': transformCSS,
        '-moz-transform': transformCSS,
        '-ms-transform': transformCSS,
        '-o-transform': transformCSS,
        'transform': transformCSS
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks so much. I need the rotation angle to stay a variable, so I liked one other answer better, but this is fantastic. Thanks so much for your work on this!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do your transformation on the `.pie`-element and not on the `.a2` or `.a3`.

Change your selector(s) to this:

```
var selector1 = ".thermometer .pieSlice1.hold .pie" + ":has(.a2)";
```